# Understanding why CLR transformed compositional data should not be used with correlation analysis

Tags: correlation, data-transformation, proportion, bias, compositional-data

A colleague of mine asked me why use proportionality when they could instead use CLR transformation followed by Pearson/spearman/biweight midcorrelation.

I vaguely remember reading why correlation following CLR transformation isn't appropriate for compositional data but I can't seem to recall the exact details on why this shouldn't be pursued and can lead to spurious associations.

I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that CLR transformed data are singular and subcompositionally incoherent.

Im familiar with how proportionality and variance log ratio are compositionally-valid association measures between components.

I’ve been linked out to this paper but I don’t have access:

> In this paper we argue why standard transformations for compositional data are not suitable for computing correlations, and why the use of raw or log-transformed data is
> neither meaningful.

> https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11004-008-9196-y

Here is a source for proportionality:

- https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004075
- https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12064-015-0220-8

My questions:

**1. Why is proportionality preferred over correlation on CLR transformed compositional data?**

**2. Why is Pearson correlation on CLR transformed compositional data  not appopriate and misleading?**

Comment: Could you please explain what "compositionally valid" means to you?  Exactly how are you thinking of computing correlation: among the variables, between the variables and something else, or something altogether different?

Comment: Correlation based components in a composition.  By compositionally-valid, I'm referring to operations that take into account the relative nature of the data like proportionality and variance log-ratio.

Comment: Since the CLR does that, it is difficult to see what your question might be.

Comment: CLR doesn't necessarily solve all of the issues around comparing components between samples/compositions like ILR does but ILR is difficult to interpret because it is in a M - 1 space. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: I don't think anybody claimed CLR was a panacea.  Please tell us *which* issues you are concerned about.  As it stands, your claim that CLR is "compositionally invalid and misleading" has no clear meaning or objective support.

Comment: I didn’t say that CLR was compositionally invalid but instead Pearson correlation on CLR transformed values.  If it wasn’t then Rho proportionality wouldn’t have need to be developed right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot make sense of that question, because the meaning of "compositionally invalid" is even more obscure when applied to a correlation.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I’ll spend some time this weekend revising my question. I see how that can be misleading.

Comment: @whuber can you check the new edits to see if they are more appropriate?